# a11y | Mac voiceover is reading aria-label and all nested text

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

Im having a weird issue in a slider I have. The basic markup is this:

```
<ol class="slider-list" aria-live="polite">
    <li class="slider-page" aria-hidden="false" aria-roledescription="slide" aria-label=" | 1 of 5">
        <ul class="col-container cols-4 rows-1">
            <li class="col item">
                <div class="entity-container">
                    <div class="entity-mask">
                        <a class="entity-link" aria-label="My Aria Label" tabindex="0">
                            <div class="entity-box">
                                <div class="aspect">
                                    <img class="thumb" src="https://someurl.com/picture.jpg">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                        <div class="entity-details">
                            <a class="entity-link" tabindex="-1">
                                <h3 class="title no_focus">
                                    <span>My Title</span>
                                </h3>
                            </a>
                            <div class="movie-release-date">My Release Date</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            ...
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="slider-page" aria-hidden="true" aria-roledescription="slide" aria-label=" | 2 of 5">
        ...
    </li>
    ...
</ol>
```

Now let me get some things out of the way - functionally and visually everything is working. As you tab through the different column items the aria-label is read, in this case `My Aria Label` is being read.

The problem is, after that aria-label is read, then all the nested text is read too, including `My Title` and `My Release Date`. Even weirder is its ALSO going up the tree and reading the siblings aria-labels all at once without any additional tabbing - its just all read but there is a pause between the proper aria-label being read and the rest of the content being read.

This is only happening in Safari and Chrome (recent versions).

Any idea what is going on here?

Comment: What screen reader and OS are you using? I tested with NVDA/Chrome, and I cannot reproduce your issue. I suspect that this may have something to do with the live region, but I can't say for certain without more info. From your description, it almost sounds like `aria-atomic`.

Comment: Mac and Mac's Voiceover

Comment: A couple of observations: `aria-live` asks the AT to announce all text inside, which is what you're complaining about. And `aria-label` does not work with everything. You can only expect 'aria-label` to work on operable content (form elements) and on elements with relevant semantic roles. It usually doesn't work on text-level elements such as `<span>`. A full list is available here: https://html5accessibility.com/stuff/2020/11/07/not-so-short-note-on-aria-label-usage-big-table-edition/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per brennanyoung's comment and my own findings before seeing their comment, `aria-live` was the problem. As the slide changed all the content was being read. By disabling this/setting this to `off` at certain times depending on the product requirements, the problem was resolved.